# While trying to import a dat file and create instance in Pyomo, it says "ValueError" as shown the picture below

Tags: pyomo

[Error in ][1][`instance = model.create_instance('input/pownet_data_camb_2022.dat')`][2]

I need to import a dat file and create instance. But, it runs to an error saysing "ValueError: Error retrieving immutable Param value (SimHours):
The Param value is undefined and no default value is specified."

model.SimHours = Param(within=PositiveIntegers)

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, I would guess SimHours is not given a value in the data file.

Comment: Thank you #Woodruff. As per your suggestion, I traced back and got where the problem has occurred.